# Getting error while Importing other groovy file in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, intellij-13

*******************Generator.groovy********************

import jenkins.model.Jenkins

import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory

import com.cs.folderCreation

//Normal code
.............................

***********************EndOfFile********************************

----------Error log--------------------------

Generator.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class com.cs.folderCreation

@ line 5, column 1.
import com.bmw.cs.folderCreation
^

1 error

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158104

Answer (score 0):

Resloved!
It was just a plugin issue.
Improper configuration can lead to unknown issues.